# Xamarin.Foms GoogleMaps MoveToRegion doesn't work

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I want to implement onAppearing, in my constructor command

```
map.MoveToRegion(defaultPin)
```

where map needs to present a map with default pin in center.

Here is a part of my codebehind class:

```
public partial class LocationPage : PostLoginContentPage
{
    public LocationPage ()
    {
        BindingContext = ViewModel = new LocationViewModel(App.ScreenHeight, App.ScreenWidth);
        InitializeComponent ();
        searchFullMapImage.IsVisible = false;
        map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;
        List<Pin> defaultPins = ViewModel.Pins;
        Pin firstPinPosition = defaultPins?.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Position != null && m.Position.Latitude != 0 && m.Position.Longitude != 0);

        LoadPins(defaultPins);
        map.SelectedPin = firstPinPosition;
        map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(firstPinPosition.Position, Distance.FromMeters(10000)), true);
    }

 //some other methods...
}
```

Also, How can I bind onClick on a button to show me a Rome for example?
I am using XF.GoogleMaps 2.3.0 and Xamarin.Forms 2.5.4.444

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
for it to properly work you need to assure the map is ready before moving the map. I'd suggest moving your code to a viewModel and binding the properties there. So you could check for mapReady (sorry if the property name is different but its something like it)

Then after you make sure the map is ready and can move.
You should make sure it is executed on the UI thread otherwise it wont move.

To assure it will you can use,

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
          map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(firstPinPosition.Position,
Distance.FromMeters(10000)), true);
});
```

Comment: To bind the onClick just create a function which will be called from the button doing the exact same code as said on the answer above. Just make sure you have the correct coordinates.

Again i'd strongly suggest the usage of commands and transfering this responsability and map bindings to the viewModel!

Comment: tnx. Do you have some example for view model and bindings? I saw separate nuget for this GoogleMpas.Bindings? DO you have some example code for this or for search pins, and then map.CameraUpdate? The example on github is so poor.

Comment: @Stefan0309 not right here because i'm away from my personal Computer. 

I will however update it in a couple of hours when i get home with the Binding example!

Comment: Great!Thank you,