# Xamarin Forms Maps, after adding a pin, moveToRegion doesnt work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have implementation that in my OnAppearing() method, if some cases fulfilled (`App.ComebackFromPages`) to add pin to the map (`App.SelectedPin`) to a map.
after that I want to moveToRegion to that pin and zoom it.

Current state: App adds the pin, I can see it on the map, but map.MoveToRegion doesnt work.

Desired state:  App adds the pin, and zoom in to that particular pin.

Here is the OnAppearing method:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

                if (App.ComebackFromPages && App.SelectedPin != null)
                {
                    if (!map.CustomPins.Any(x => x.IdObjectInstance == App.SelectedPin.IdObjectInstance))
                    {
                        map.CustomPins.Add(App.SelectedPin);
                        App.MapPins.Add(App.SelectedPin);
                    }

                    map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(App.SelectedPin.Position, Distance.FromMiles(0.5)));

                    App.ComebackFromPages = false;
                }
        }
```

My guess is that maybe OnApperiang method is async? and its not on the main thread?

Comment: Though the **OnApperiang** method is async, it doesn't start a new task. So the code is called in the main thread. We need to make sure the map is ready before moving the map. You could move the code in a button click event to check that. Check the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291105/xamarin-foms-googlemaps-movetoregion-doesnt-work

Comment: I solved this issue adding `await Task.Delay(500)` between adding a pin to map and calling the method map.MpveToRegion.

Comment: Congrats! Please post an answer and accept it. It will be beneficial for other community members who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue adding await Task.Delay(500) between adding a pin to map and calling the method map.MpveToRegion